# Check of overflow in signed addition and abelian groups

Tags: c, types, integer, integer-overflow, integer-arithmetic

I was reading about why the following code is buggy:

```
int tadd_ok ( int x, int y ) {  
    int sum = x + y;  
    return ( sum - x == y ) && ( sum - y == x );  
}
```

The explanation was that two's complement addition forms an abelian group and so the expression
`(x + y) - x` with evaluate to `y` regardless if whether or not the addition overflows.
(Same for `(x + y) - y)` which will evaluate to `x`).

I don't understand this explanation or the abelian group reference. Two's complement addition is basically unsigned modulo arithmetic that is "converted" to two's complement, right?
So for example if we have 4 bits we have the range [-8, 7].
In the example if we had `x = 7` and `y = 6` the result overflows to 6. And that is not equal to either `y` or `x`.
So why is the explanation that the equality is always valid regardless of the overflow?

Comment: It's true for unsigned integers, for signed integers (e.g., `int`) the overflow invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ouah:When you say it is true, are you referring to my `...Two's complement addition is basically unsigned modulo arithmetic that is "converted" to two's complement, right?`

Comment: I'm referring to `(x + y) - x` evaluating to `x`.

Answer (score 4):

An "abelian" group just means that the order that you add things doesn't matter - (a+b)+c = a+(b+c) and (a+b) == (b+a).

This is true of the integers in C.  It is technically true as @ouah points out that overflow is undefined, but this is to support the C standard easily on processors that do not use two's compliment math.  Most do.

On those, unless something very strange (or not so strange, but optimized - thanks @ouah) is going on in the compiler, unsigned math will function as an abelian group.

In your example, 7+6 = 0111 + 0110 == 1101 is -(0010+1) = -3.  Negative numbers "count downward" in binary in a twos' complement signed system: 1111 is -1.   Subtracting back yields 1010, or 0101+1 = 6.

Comment: *"this is to support the C standard easily on processors that do not use two's compliment math. Most do."* Modern C compilers actively perform optimizations based on the idea that signed overflow is undefined.

Comment: Unsigned math will always function as a group -- the standard requires it.  Signed math is not required to by the C spec, but most processors use 2s complement which is a group.  Unfortunatley, the C spec does not require the compiler to use the machine's 2s complement operations in all cases -- the optimizer can choose to do something else when overflows occur.

Comment: @ouah - Interesting.  Can you provide a citation and/or show us a program compiled in gcc that produces such behavior?  I have never seen it.

Comment: @BadZen:1)If (a + b) can overflow then how can the order of addition not matter? 2) `1011` is -3 so far ok. I lost you in the `...Subtracting back yields 1010` What does that mean? We got -3. What is this subtracking back?

Comment: "Subtracting back" == evaluating the first expression on the left in your return line above.  Think of it this way:  moving to signed from unsigned in a 2's complement system of n bits is like evaluating the invertible map that sends [0..2^{n-1}-1] to [0..2^{n-1}-1], and [2^{n-1}..2^n-1] to [-2^{n-1}..-1], in order.   That is to say f(x) = x for the first branch, and f(x) = -(2^n-x) in the second.   Put this way, you can easily verify the commutative and associative properties I've claimed (ie. abelian).

Comment: @BadZen Real life example: `int foo(int a) { return (x * 10) / 10; }`. Compile with `gcc` `-O0` and with `-O3`. Compute for example `foo(INT_MAX);`. With `-O3`, `(x * 10) / 10` is folded into `x` by exploiting the undefined behavior of signed overflows.

Comment: @BadZen:`Subtracting back yields 1010, or 0101+1 = 6`.But it is `-3-7=-10=10110` which becomes `0110` (truncates to 4 bits) which is 3 which is not equal to x. Why subtracting back gives 1010? Also 1010 is -6 and not 6 as you mention.

Comment: 0110 = 2^2*1 + 2^1*1 + 2^0*0 = 4+2 = 6.

Comment: @BadZen:You are right. My bad. `0110` is 6.But what is the 1010 in your answer: `...yields 1010, or 0101+1 = 6.`

Comment: To negate a two's complement number, you invert the binary digits and then add 1.  The 1010 is the raw value of the subtraction (you get to "borrow" a bit from the non-existent fifth-bit column, if you will)

Comment: @BadZen:`To negate a two's complement number, you invert the binary digits and then add 1` But this is the process for one's complement

Comment: No, you don't add a 1 for one's complement - no offset because there is a -0.  We're not working in ones' complement at all, as you indicated.  If you're on a ones' complement machine, I'm not actually sure how overflow is "supposed to" work.   Again, it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old question, but hope my answer will be useful for someone.

This is because to fix a positive overflow (when `x + y > TYPE_MAX`) we need to subtract `2^n` from the sum and to fix a negative one (when `x + y < TYPE_MIN`) we need to add `2^n` (a bunch of math statements are needed to show this, so I decided not to include them in the answer).

Therefore if `x + y` is positively overflowed `sum` actually equals to `x + y - 2^n`. After this when we perform comparison we subtract `x` from `sum` which causes a negative overflow and hence we have `sum - x` actually equals to `sum - x + 2^n`. Thus, `sum - x + 2^n = x + y - 2^n - x + 2^n = x`. The same happens with another preposition.